# WebLogic JAX-WS EE client to WS-Security service on localhost

Tags: weblogic, jax-ws, ws-security, weblogic12c

I have a JAX-WS endpoint which uses WS-Security, specifically the WebLogic pre-written Wssp1.2-2007-Wss1.1-UsernameToken-Plain-X509-Basic256.xml policy. I have a working command-line client where I build all the client credential providers and trust managers. Everything works great.

Now I also need to have another EE module deployed separately to the same server. According to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13713/message.htm#i251852 I'm supposed to code the EE client as-if there was no security related WS-Policy at all but it doesn't work. Either I'm completely failing on setting up the credential mapping (which wouldn't surprise me because the documentation is lacking) or what I think seems to be more likely, the credential mapping isn't actually happening because I'm talking to localhost.

How do you create an JAX-WS EE client that uses a WS-Security enabled service on localhost? (I'd also like to see an remote host example too)